# Error when I deploy by ng build --prod Angular 4.3.2

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I've upgraded angular from 4.0.0 to 4.3.2 by:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest rxjs@latest --save
```

Then I put `ng serve` and works well but when I want to deploy by `ng build --prod` I have the following errors:

```
[1m[33mWARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
730:2-27 "export 'ɵNgModuleInjector' (imported as 'import0') was not found in '@angular/core'[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (11,49): Property 'ɵNgModuleInjector' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Data/angular4/system/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (41,79): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (45,76): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (46,38): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (46,70): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (46,99): Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Injector'.
  Type 'ApplicationModuleInjector' is not assignable to type 'Injector'.
    Property 'get' is missing in type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (46,109): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (46,147): Property 'componentFactoryResolver' does not exist on type 'ApplicationModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/core/core.ngfactory.ts (67,94): Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'NgModuleFactory'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/common.ngfactory.ts (11,44): Property 'ɵNgModuleInjector' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Data/angular4/system/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/common.ngfactory.ts (18,111): Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'CommonModuleInjector'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/common/common.ngfactory.ts (33,84): Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'NgModuleFactory'.[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in C:/Data/angular4/system/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.ngfactory.ts (12,45): Property 'ɵNgModuleInjector' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Data/angular4/system/node_modules/@angular/core/core"'.[39m[22m
```

Also I'm showing File Content: main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I'm checking on Internet about this but I don't find the reason to solve. What could it be missing?

Comment: Things to consider: did you delete node_modules before install? Did you clean npm cache?

Comment: I didn't delete node_modules. I executed npm cache clean and then ng build --prod but appears the same error list above

Comment: Likely from cross contamination if you didn't delete node_modules then clean cache before the fresh install

Comment: Ok. I deleted node_modules, cleaned cache, installed again. Well I have error list about app.module.ngfactory.ts. Also it says I have an error in main.ts. Just it case, the content file of main.ts is above. The error says: ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Data\angular4\system\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: Angular latest isn't necessarily compatible with latest RxJS and TypeScript, you'd be better looking at what is set by e.g. `ng new` or in the [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

Comment: To extend on what @jonrsharpe mentioned, do a global install of angular-cli `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then use the ng new. Also note: Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

Comment: I was checking and experimenting the issue and I did the following steps: 1) Uninstall node js, 2) remove the npm folder located in c:\windows\user\user1\appdata\roaming\npm 3) install node js 4) restart the pc, 5) in node cmd to execute ng new project 6) upgrade angular (I see the latest is 4.3.3 now). Until here ng build works but when I started to test the web app I see a critical bug, the *ngIf was not working for me. If one template has several subtemplates through divs with *ngIf respectively. It show all subtemplates and not what I wish.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the $$_gendir issue after days with the following in package.json:

- typescript Version 2.3.3 ("typescript": "~2.3.3")
- script/prod: "ng build --env=prod --aot=true"

The main issue was the wrong typescript Version.